cert-manager letsencrypt certificate give cert-manager.local on browser
After getting certificate from issuer
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: tuanhuynh.contact@gmail.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            ingressClassName: haproxy

kubectl get certificate -o wide
NAME                  READY   SECRET                ISSUER                STATUS                                          AGE
dallasoft-nginx-tls   True    dallasoft-nginx-tls   letsencrypt-staging   Certificate is up to date and has not expired   10m

Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mydomain-nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  ingressClassName: haproxy
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: mydomain-nginx-tls  # Adjust to match your certificate secret name
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx  # Make sure this matches the name of your Nginx service
            port:
              number: 80

When open mydomain.com/nginx on browser, certificate with issuer name:
cert-manager.local

How to get the browser recognize the ssl certificate?

It works when I change to use ClusterIssuer with LetsEncrypt Pro
Issuer
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: abc@gmail.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
            ingressClassName: haproxy

Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mydomain-nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: haproxy
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: mydomain-nginx-tls-prod  # Adjust to match your certificate secret name
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
    paths:
    - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
        service:
            name: nginx  # Make sure this matches the name of your Nginx service
            port:
            number: 80

